# R - renaming files in directory in the correct order

Tags: r, file, directory, file-rename

I used `RSelenium` to download multiple (125) spreadsheets with data that I need from a webpage to a directory. The file generated by the website was always named "report", so it was download with filenames ranging from "report (1)" to "report (124)".

I have a character vector with names for the files that I was hoping to use to rename them using 'file.rename'. However, while the files show up in the order downloaded in the folder (I'm using Windows 10 FYI), when I use `list.files` it gives it to me in the following order (results abbreviated to first 25; I manually renamed the first file to "areport.xls" to put it first).

```
[1] "areport.xls"     "report (1).xls"  "report (10).xls" "report (11).xls" "report (12).xls" "report (13).xls" "report (14).xls"
 [8] "report (15).xls" "report (16).xls" "report (17).xls" "report (18).xls" "report (19).xls" "report (2).xls"  "report (20).xls"
[15] "report (21).xls" "report (22).xls" "report (23).xls" "report (24).xls" "report (3).xls"  "report (4).xls"  "report (5).xls" 
[22] "report (6).xls"  "report (7).xls"  "report (8).xls"  "report (9).xls"
```

There seems to be no rhyme or reason for the order (I imagine because the filenames are read in as strings?). I need a way to read the file names in the correct order so that they will be given the correct new name.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that there is a function in the gtools library is really the only explanation that is needed:

```
> library(gtools)
> x <- scan(what="")
1: "areport.xls"     "report (1).xls"  "report (10).xls" "report (11).xls" "report (12).xls" "report (13).xls" "report (14).xls"
8: "report (15).xls" "report (16).xls" "report (17).xls" "report (18).xls" "report (19).xls" "report (2).xls"  "report (20).xls"
15: "report (21).xls" "report (22).xls" "report (23).xls" "report (24).xls" "report (3).xls"  "report (4).xls"  "report (5).xls" 
22: "report (6).xls"  "report (7).xls"  "report (8).xls"  "report (9).xls"
26: 
Read 25 items
> ?mixedsort
> mixedsort(x)
 [1] "areport.xls"     "report (1).xls"  "report (2).xls"  "report (3).xls"  "report (4).xls"  "report (5).xls"  "report (6).xls" 
 [8] "report (7).xls"  "report (8).xls"  "report (9).xls"  "report (10).xls" "report (11).xls" "report (12).xls" "report (13).xls"
[15] "report (14).xls" "report (15).xls" "report (16).xls" "report (17).xls" "report (18).xls" "report (19).xls" "report (20).xls"
[22] "report (21).xls" "report (22).xls" "report (23).xls" "report (24).xls"
```